# Merge one mesh with another without modyfing geometry? (So not a boolean, more like adding mesh data)

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I have an object with a bunch of modifiers on it and I want to merge another object with the first one through some kind of modifier in order for the added geometry to be affected by the modifiers that come after in the stack. To be clear the second object geometry would be instanced and still editable.

Is that something Blender can do? Kind of like a boolean modifier union except I don't want any merging occurring.

By the way I tried doing it with the boolean modifier in union mode with a very high overlap threshold but it doesn't work reliably. Also it mess up the UV mapping from the first object which is something I don't want.

Just to be clear I don't want to add the modifiers to the second object, I want it to be easy, simple, and non-destructive.

Comment: You can join the meshes with ctrl+j. Select both objects, the one without modifiers first, then the one with modifiers (making it the "active" selection), and then ctrl+j, this will merge the objects into one, retaining all the modifiers of the active object (whatever was selected last), and applying them to the added mesh from the second object.

Comment: Just read the post please. "To be clear the second object geometry would be instanced and still editable." I obviously don't want to CTRL+J, this is a more advanced question.

Comment: Hello :). There's a great addon called *Bool Tool*, that allows non-destructive Boolean operations through modifiers. I can post a full answer with examples, if you're interested. It looks perfect for your situation.